# Python - module import breaks after running

Tags: python

I have an issue where the module import workflow breaks after I start developing.

I am using Spyder (Editor, and the IPython Console) and a conda virtual env. I have a directory similar to:

```
C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Python Scripts\package\     
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
    extra_files/        
        moduleZ.py
    moduleA.py
    moduleB.py
```

PATH includes: C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Python Scripts\package

Step 1) When I first open Spyder, and in the IPython Console:

```
import moduleA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduleA'
```

Step 2) In IPython:

```
import package.moduleA  <--- Works!
```

Step 3) Open moduleA.py in the Spyder editor. **Run file.**  It runs through, no issues. <--- Works!

Step 4) Repeat step 2. In IPython:

```
import package.moduleA  <--- Doesnt Work!

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

Step 5) Repeat step 1...in the IPython Console:

```
import moduleA   <---- works!!
```

This is driving me nuts.... I've never had this issue before.  I'm simply trying to make *package* available in my environment, and so I can do relative imports etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add the package to PYTHONPATH env variable

Comment: If you want `package` to be importable, then you want the PYTHONPATH to contain `C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Python Scripts`, not `C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Python Scripts\package`

Comment: Got it..... that makes sense!     I would prefer moduleA, moduleB to be directly importable, how would I change the PATH so I could do that?

Comment: Also, whats the difference between PYTHONPATH and just, PATH?

Comment: @wim - I tried that, but I'm still having the same issue.